# Splitting a string into words and punctuation with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working in Ruby and I want to split a string and its punctuation into an array, but I want to consider apostrophes and hyphens as parts of words.  For example,

```
s = "here...is a     happy-go-lucky string that I'm writing"
```

should become

```
["here", "...", "is", "a", "happy-go-lucky", "string", "that", "I'm", "writing"].
```

The closest I've gotten is still inadequate because it doesn't properly consider hyphens and apostrophes as part of the word.

This is the closest I've gotten so far:

```
s.scan(/\w+|\W+/).select {|x| x.match(/\S/)}
```

which yields

```
["here", "...", "is", "a", "happy", "-", "go", "-", "lucky", "string", "that", "I", "'", "m", "writing"]
```

.

Comment: If apostrophes  are part of the word, why isn't `here...is` a whole word?

Comment: `here` and `is` are separate words semantically, even though the text I'm analyzing sometimes involves bad punctuation habits (I'm parsing some Yelp reviews ^_^).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
s.scan(/[\w'-]+|[[:punct:]]+/)
#=> ["here", "...", "is", "a", "happy-go-lucky", "string", "that", "I'm", "writing"]
```

Comment: Wow can you reference where you got the `:punct:` stuff from?

Comment: You can reference the POSIX classes [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
s.scan(/[\w'-]+|[.,!?]+/)
```

The idea is we match either words with possibly `'`/`-` in them or punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

After nearly giving up then tinkering some more, I appear to have solved the puzzle.  This seems to work: `s.scan(/[\w'-]+|\W+/).select {|x| x.match(/\S/)}`.  It yields `["here", "...", "is", "a", "happy-go-lucky", "string", "that", "I'm", "writing"]`.

Is there an even cleaner way to do it though, without having to use `#select`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split`method.

Example:

```
str = "word, anotherWord, foo"
puts str.split(",")
```

It returns

```
word
anotherWord
foo
```

Hope it works for you!

Also you can chek this http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/split.htm