# Is there a way to split a string by spaces and commas but preserving the coma in the resulting array?

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this:

`"my bike, is very big"`

and i would like to split it in the following way.

```
["my","bike",",","is","very","big"]
```

Comment: @Jörg, this is not really a dup of the earlier question as there are more focused answers that can be used here, such as `"my bike, is very big".split(/ *(,) *| +/)`.

Comment: The question seems clear; I don't understand the downvotes. If a reader does not understand it a comment asking for clarification would be more helpful that a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take on it.

```
text = "my bike, is very big"
text_array = text.split(/(\W+)/)
parsed_text_array = text_array.map { |item| 
    next if item.eql?(" ")
    item.strip
}.compact

print parsed_text_array

# ~> ["my", "bike", ",", "is", "very", "big"]
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

While this `#scan` with regex solution from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32037433/9785060) is perfect. I felt like including a non-regex solution too:

```
str = "my bike, is very big"

str = str.split(",").flat_map { |x| [x, ","] }[0...-1].map(&:split).flatten

p str

#-> ["my", "bike", ",", "is", "very", "big"]
```